# how to submit an oozie coordinator job

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have an oozie coordinator job which is defined in file coordinator.xml, it runs a workflow job which is defined in the workflow.xml file. I'd like to run the coordinator job but when I issue the command 'oozie job -oozie http://.../oozie/ -config ./job.properties -run' it runs the workflow not the coordinator. How can I tell it to run th coordinator not the workflow?

Comment: It runs the workflow? I thought this would create a co-ordinator job which creates a workflow job when it gets into running status.Are you trying to test the co-ordinators only? If then you use dry run https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Dryrun_of_Coordinator_Job

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution, it is basicallly changing the 'oozie.wf.application.path' property in the property file to 'oozie.coord.application.path'

Answer (score 0):

You can also run a Workflow or submit a coordinator using a java client, if that works
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/client/apidocs/org/apache/oozie/client/OozieClient.html